# Ionic html array without *ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic3, ngfor

How would I get data from an Array in Ionic 3 without having to use ngFor?

For example, this works

```
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let user of users">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <strong>Name:</strong>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            {{user.name}}
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-item> 
    <ion-item-options side="left">
      <button ion-button (click)="delete()">
        <ion-icon name="ios-trash"></ion-icon> Delete
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
```

But my users array only has 1 row, so how can I access the data without having to loop through the array using *ngFor?

Something like this?

```
{{users[0].id}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use {{users[0].id}}

Answer (score 1):

As Alex said, you can use the example provided.

If you are unsure if the array has any objects, you can do something like `{{ users.length > 0 ? users[0].id : '' }}`
or if you have many fields to display:

```
<div *ngIf="users.length > 0">
  <span>{{ users[0].id }}</span>
<div>
```

---

If you need to also check for undefined or null, just add that to the check.
F.ex.:

```
<div *ngIf="users !== undefined && users !== null && users.length > 0">
  <span>{{ users[0].id }}</span>
<div>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me? it returns `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.users[0].id')`, but works in the ngFor loop? Sorry if i'm missing something obvious, i'm fairly new to angular and ionic!

Comment: Well either _co, users, or users[0] is undefined. If you find out which you can check it. Typically it is undefined before you get the data, thats why it fails.